# Shell script “for” loop syntax

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I have gotten the following to work:

```
i=0
for log in $(ls -1dt import*.log)
do
((i++))
if [ $i -gt 3 ]; then
rm -rf $log
fi
done
```

It produces a: `"syntax error near unexpected token 'do' "`
Can anybody help?

Comment: is it a bash script?

Comment: Ups...Sorry! Yes, its a bash script "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: Could it be related to [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)?

Comment: Could it be that your script has windows line ending (CR LF)?

Comment: The *complete* error message would probably confirm DOS line endings. In a file named `tmp.sh`, I get (using `bash` 3.2) ``'mp.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpended token `do``. Note the `t` missing at the beginning of the line. `bash` 4.4 provides a clearer error message, indicating the unexpected token is `$'do\r'`.

Comment: Cant reproduce it. If you've written the script on a windows machine, run `sed -i 's/\r$//' SCRIPTNAME` to remove trailing `\r` of the script and run it again

Comment: run `dos2unix your_script_file` and then retry

Comment: Could be that there are exotic chars in filenames: `"`, `space`, `\n`, ... Please add the output of this command: `for logf in import*.log ; do printf "'%s'\n" "${logf}" ; done`

Comment: Incidentally, this is the wrong way to iterate over a list of files anyway; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @Jayjargot The syntax error occurs during parsing, before the command substitution is evaluated.

Comment: @chepner: haaaaaaa, yes

Comment: Getting the oldest/newest files or ordering by some file attribute is not quite simple: [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and [BashFAQ/099](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099) are good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic to do the same thing without parsing `ls` -

```
stat -c "%Y %n" import*.log | # list last modification and filename
  sort -rn                  | # sort reverse numeric on mod time
  while read es fn;           # read the timestamp and the filename
  do if (( ++latest <= 3 ));  # count each file found, for 1st 3
     then continue;           # do nothing, skipping them
     else rm -f "$fn";        # -r for recurse only needed on dir's
     fi;
  done
```

Comment: But you still have to handle CRLF line endings.